# xml parser with android

Tags: android, xml

I have some .xml file that are encoded in UTF-8. But whenever I try to parse it on Eclipse 
my app doesn't run,

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<music>
  <song>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Someone Like You</title>
    <artist>Adele</artist>
    <duration>4:47</duration>
    <thumb_url>http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png</thumb_url>
  </song>
</music>
```

I get this error :

> E/Error:(540): Unexpected token (position:TEXT ï»¿1 in java.io.StringReader@412d05e0)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Although I've tested on another xml link found on the web, it worked just fine!!

```
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
  String xml = null

  try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  // return XML
  return xml;
}
```

Comment: It just seems like there is an unrecognised character in your XML file which is causing the parser to blow up.

Comment: here's my xml http://www.myapp.host-ed.me/please.xml

Comment: You need to reduce your XML to a small sample that illustrates the problem, and then include that XML in your question (not as a link, but actually as part of the question). The reason for that is that your question should stand on it's own; using a link to an external site that contains important content makes your question meaningless if that external content is not available. Also, having important content off-site makes it unsearchable by future users of SO. Please edit your question to include it (and you might also want to do a quick review of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I've solved my problem by changing the encoding to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`